# How to randomly update a table?

Tags: mysql, random

How can I update a table by attributing random values? I wish to randomize the column `isOnline`

```
id | name   | isOnline

1 | johndoe | 1
2 | janedoe | 1
3 | marydoe | 0
4 | teendoe | 0
5 | babydow | 1
```

**Query**

```
UPDATE users
SET isOnline = rand(int)
WHERE isOnline='1' OR isOnline='0';
```

Comment: Errrrrr Tell me what the point is of randomising a value that can be 1 or 0 is.

Answer (score 2):

[`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) generates a random floating number between 0 and 1. What you want is simply to generate an integer between 0 and 1 (i.e. 0 OR 1). This should do the trick:

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 2)
```

Here is a proof-of-concept SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b62a0/1

p/s: Actually, the actual way to generate integers between a range of n <= integer < m is this:

```
FLOOR(n + (RAND() * m))
```

However, since n = 0 and m = 2, we can simplify that to:

```
FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 2))
```

or:

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 2)
```

Comment: I think this would always generates `1` rather than 0 and 1 coz rand never generates 0

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Whoops, you're correct. Updated the answer now :)

Comment: still nothing will change coz multiply by 2 will never result in 0

Comment: @AnkitBajpai The `FLOOR()` function solves that. E.g. `FLOOR(0.25)` gives you 0. `FLOOR(1.5)` gives you 1.